# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error writing a linked list

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list, singly-linked-list, lvalue

I am currently learning some C++ for a course I am taking in school.  I have basic understanding of lvalues and rvalues, but I am unable to determine why I am receiving a compiler error.

I am creating a singly linked list and need to be able to reverse it.  As per my assignment I have two classes. The first is the node and just holds an int as well as a pointer.

```
 class Node {
  int data;
  Node *next;

  public:
    //Constructor
    Node(int d) {
      data = d;
      next = NULL;}

    //Set to next Node
    void SetNext(Node *nextOne) {
      next = nextOne;}

    //Returns data value
    int Data(){return data;}

    //Returns next Node
    Node *Next() {return next;}
};
```

Then I have a linked list class that has a header pointer and then a number of functions for adding, printing etc. the list.

```
class LinkedList {
  Node *head;

  public:
    //Constructor
    LinkedList(){head = NULL;}

    void AddNode(int d) {
      //Create a new Node
      Node *newNode = new Node(d);

      //Create a temporary pointer
      Node *temp = head;

      //If there are already nodes in the list
      if(temp != NULL) {
        //Parse through to the end of the list
        while(temp->Next() != NULL) {
          temp = temp->Next();}
        //Point the last Node in the list to the new Node
        temp->SetNext(newNode);
      }

      //If adding as the first Node
      else{
        head = newNode;}
    }

    void PrintList() {
      //Temporary pointer
      Node *temp = head;

      //If there are no nodes in the list
      if(temp == NULL) {
        std::cout << "The list is empty" << std::endl;}

      //If there is only one node in the list
      if(temp->Next() == NULL) {
          std::cout << temp->Data() << std::endl;}

        //Parse through the list and print
      else {
        do {
          std::cout << temp->Data();
          temp = temp->Next();
        }
        while(temp != NULL);
      }
    }

    //Returns the number of nodes in the list
    int CountList() {
      //Temporary pointer
      Node *temp = head;
      //Counter variable
      int counter = 0;

      //If the list is empty
      if(temp == NULL) {
        return counter;}

      //Parse through Nodes counting them
      else {
        do {counter++;
          temp = temp->Next();
        }
        while(temp != NULL);
      }
      return counter;
    }

    //Reverses the list
    Node *ReverseList() {
      //Initially set to NULL then tracks the new head
      Node *marker = NULL;
      //Tracks the next one in the list
      Node *nextOne;

      //Sets the first Node to NULL and then sets the last Node to point to
      //the first one and rotates through the list pointing the last to the
      //first
      while(head != NULL) {
        nextOne = head->Next();
        head->Next() = marker;
        marker = head;
        head = nextOne;
      }
      //Setting the head back to the start again
      head = marker;
    }

};
```

One of those functions is supposed to reverse the list.  The line "head->Next() = marker;" in the ReverseList function is causing a "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error when compiling.

Any insight as to why this is occurring and how I can correct the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please make this a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return from the call to `Next()` is an rvalue. As you are in a class function, you don't need to call the `Next` function to get at the private `next` pointer, you can just use it directly.

```
head->next = marker;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Next() function returns a pointer, and you then do this:

```
head->Next() = marker;
```

You're changing the pointer to marker and not what it's pointing at. To solve this you need to dereference that pointer:

```
*head->Next() = marker;
```

Answer (score 0):

your signature for next is:

```
Node *Next() {return next;}
```

This makes a copy of next pointer at return and hence it is treated as r-value and not l-value.

One way of overcoming this would be to use a pointer-to-pointer:.

```
 Node **Next() {return &next;}
```

And then use it as:

```
  int main()
  { 
  Node* marker=new Node(89);
  Node* nod=new Node(9);
  *(nod->Next())= marker;


  cout<<(nod->next)->data<<endl;
  cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   return 0;
  }
```

This makes it more complicated to use.

Comment: Although this fixes the error, it rather ruins encapsulation, OP perhaps needs to redesign his class's interface

Comment: idea of encapsulation is good but it also depends on whether he is planning to use this as a library or some other way.